# Assignment in conditional expression

Tags: javascript, for-loop, compiler-errors

I am trying to learn JavaScript at Codecademy. I am working on [this problem](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-XEDZA/0/5) about for loops, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. It says "Assignment in conditional expression," but I don't know what that means. It is saying the error is at the second `for` statement.

The goal is to change the value of `hits` to however many times my name was included in the `text` variable string.

Here is my code:

```js
var text ="Max Gee Max Gee Max Gee";    
var myName = "Max";
var hits=[];
for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    if(text[i]==="M"){
        for(var j = i;j = myName.length;){
            hits.push("Max");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the assignment supposed to do? Conditional as in `if`.

Comment: give the link of the assignment

Comment: @AtishDipongkor http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-XEDZA/0/5?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Overall it is supposed to change hits to how many time my name was in the var text

Comment: @hicurin Edited and it is now included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is assignment, but in conditional statements you need to check for equality (`==`), check if something is greater (`>`), check if something is less (`<`) etc. You are assigning the variable `j` the length of `myName` rather than checking some condition on this line:

```
for(var j = i;j = myName.length;){
```

Instead you probably need to do something like this:

```
for(var j = i;j <= myName.length;){
```

However, this may not necessarily be the solution to your Codecademy Assignment, but it will solve your specific javascript error. play around with and read up on `<`, `>`, `==` and the other conditionals mentioned [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) to try to figure out what works.

**Edit:** if you wanted a solution to your entire problem, it would have been helpful to post a link to the problem in the question and not only mention the specific error you were getting, but explain the entire question. That being said, you missed a few things here:

1. You were doing assignment instead of checking a condition as I explained above.
2. You forgot to increment `j` in your `for` loop as Franklin mentioned in the comments. You need to do `j++`.
3. You are not stopping at the correct point in the string. As Codecademy says, "...your second `for` loop should stop when it reaches its current point in the string + `myName.length`." This means that you need to stop at `text.length + myName.length` instead of just `myName.length`. That also means you should use `<` rather than `<=` as I recommended above.

Putting all of that together, the solution is to put this line:

```
for(var j = i;j < (text.length + myName.length); j++){
```

in place of of this line:

```
for(var j = i;j = myName.length;){
```

Comment: Alright I changed it to this and this is what codecademy is saying: Oops, try again. Careful: your second 'for' loop should stop when it reaches its current point in the string + myName.length.

Comment: I edited my answer and tried to give a little more explanation.

Comment: @maxgee, I edited my answer to include the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `for (var j = i; j === myName.length; ) {`

You're using an assignment where you should be using a conditional/boolean.

Comment: I changed it to that and the website told me this back: 
Oops, try again. Careful: your second 'for' loop should stop when it reaches its current point in the string + myName.length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
    hits.push(text[j]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was struggling that also and finally I've understood, what codecademy are saying: ".. its current point in the string + myName.length"
Just need to add myName.length.

```
var text = "Aoday I woke up beside the loveliest girl on planet Earth";
var myName = "Aleksei";
var hits = [];
for(i=0; i < text.length; i++){
    if(text[0] === myName[0]){
        for(var j = i; j <= myName.length; j++){
           hits.push(text[j] + myName.length);
            }
        }
    }
```

and by the way text's and myName's content should start both same letter. Hope I am right and hope it helps!